# angular-ui-router views and controllers are not loading after upgrading to angular 1.3

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

after I did the update to angular 1.3 I'm not able to reach the controllers and views, they simply doesn't load.

the states in my root works perfectly, this is my app.js

```
$stateProvider.state("root",
    {
        url: '',
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            'footer@': {
                templateUrl: "/partial/footer/footer.html",

            },
            'header@': {
                templateUrl: "/partial/header/header.html",
            }
        }
    }).state('root.home', {
            url: '/index',
            views: {
                'container@': {
                    templateUrl: '/partial/index/index.html',
                    controller: 'IndexCtrl'
                }
            }
        }
    ).state('root.welcome', {
        url: '/index/:status',
        views: {
            'container@': {
                templateUrl: '/partial/index/index.html',
                controller: 'IndexCtrl'
            }
        }
    });
```

an also my configuration:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('index');
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
$locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: false });
```

by after doing a stage.go or just by typing the url, **I'm not able to reach any route in these states**:

```
$stateProvider.state("candidate",
    {
        url: '',
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            'footer@': {
                templateUrl: "/partial/footer/footer.html"
             },
            'header@': {
                templateUrl: "/user/partial/user.header/user.header.html",
            },
            'sideBar@': {
                templateUrl: '/user/partial/user.sidebar/user.sidebar.html',
                controller: 'SidebarCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    user: 'currentUser'
                }
            },
            'navBar@': {
                templateUrl: '/user/partial/navbar/navbar.html'
            }
        }
    }).state('candidate.dashboard',
    {
        url: '/dashboard',
        views: {
            'container@': {
                templateUrl: '/user/partial/user.dashboard/user.dashboard.html',
                controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    dashboardinfo: function ($resource, tracker) {
                        var resourceGet = $resource('/user/dashboard');
                        var promise = resourceGet.get().$promise;
                        tracker.addPromise(promise);
                        return promise;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

I've spent a couple of hours trying to figure this out without any luck, maybe it's just a small detail I'm missing, any advice will be more than welcome.

PS: I'm using v0.2.12-pre1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turns out that the resolve method was failing, I'm using angular promise tracker

```
 var resourceGet = $resource('/user/dashboard');
 var promise = resourceGet.get().$promise;
 tracker.addPromise(promise); <-- fails here
 return promise;
```

it seems like resources and promises have breaking changes and my implementation could be deprecated.

Comment: Great job, great to see you did it, sir!

Answer (score 2):

I tried to replicate the issue, mentioned above in [this working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GDRGx7FfBmrxrs445eJY?p=preview). All the code is almost unchanged, I just used **a custom version of `UI-Router`**. The reason is this reported and known bug:

- [Impossible to disable html5Mode with angular 1.3.0-rc.3 #1397](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1397) *(small cite:)*

> Due to: [angular/angular.js@dc3de7f](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/dc3de7fb7a14c38b5c3dc7decfafb0b51d422dd1)
>    the html5mode-check in urlRouter.js [line 383] is no longer correct. And thus it's impossible to disable html5mode.
>   A quick fix could be:

```
var isHtml5 = $locationProvider.html5Mode();
if (angular.isObject(isHtml5)) {
  isHtml5 = isHtml5.enabled;
}
```

And this (the code above) is **the change** I made. Nothing else. All the code started to work then...

Check also this answer

- [ui-router not producing correct href attribute in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26668832/1679310)

for a Chris T link to fixed version...

Comment: the weird thing is that I'm using master-0.2.12-pr1 branch :/

Comment: Can hardly comment branch, but my last check was - build is failing. Anyhow, if this will help, would be very happy. Let me know about the result...

Comment: I've corroborated and I'm using the v0.2.12-pre1 and your change is in line 1723, but it's still not working I'll post if I find any issue.

Comment: I see... great. Congratulations.